# Unable to upload file to Azure BLOB using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I was using Multer to upload files to Azure BLOB.
Till now I was declaring the Multer object like this:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: new MulterAzureStorage({
        azureStorageConnectionString: '...',
        containerName: '...',
        containerSecurity: '...'
    })
}).single("path/to/upload");
```

Then I was invoking the Multer object like:

```
upload(req,res,  function(err) { })
```

But now I'm trying to make the functionality dynamic, previously the `string("upload")` inside

```
single("upload")
```

block was hard coded, now I was trying to use a variable instead of that like this

```
var uploadPath = "path/to/upload";
single(uploadPath)
```

but it is not working like this.
Right now the full code looks like this,

```
const helperUpload = async (uploadPath, req, res,) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let upload = () => multer({
      storage: new MulterAzureStorage({
        azureStorageConnectionString: '...',
        containerName: '...',
        containerSecurity: '...',
      })
    }).single(uploadPath);

    upload(req,res,  function(err) {
      console.log("inside callback");
      if (err) {
          console.log("unable to upload");
          resolve(false);
      } else if (req.file) {
          console.log("File = "+JSON.stringify(req.file));
          console.log("uploaded");
          resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the issue..?

Comment: no it seems that the uploadPath needs to be static to work properly

Comment: Any news on that?